# Laravel pass message from function to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the error message returned by the API in my function to be shown in the controller, but it is returning null even if I set the error variable myself, i.e:  `$error = 'Error Message'`

**Function:**

```
class ImportexportDomains {
public function add($input) {
       $error = $data['message'];
       return $error;
}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function store() {
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
    $addnew = new ImportexportDomains;
    $addnew->add($input);
    dd($addnew);
}

$addnew

ImportexportDomains {#285 ▼
  +error: null
}
```

Comment: where does `$data` come from? you are not catching the `return` value. you are setting a local `$error` variable, this will be deleted when the function exits. Do you have any idea how classes work?

Comment: @NDM $data is from the API - Im new to laravel and learning as I go so not 100% sure on some things, how do I catch the return value?

Comment: read some basic php tutorials before diving into a framework. learn about functions and classes.

Comment: Also, you are using obsolete Laravel Facades and functions.

Comment: so what I'm trying to do is not possible this way?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function add($input) {
       $error = $data['message'];
       return $error;
}
```

In the function above `$input` was never used, Whatsoever you pass later as parameter in that function will do nothing.

```
public function add($input) {
      $error = "";
      if($input == ""){
      $error = "Not valid input";
}

return $error;
}
```

This might not be exactly what you want, but you can get idea from that.

Answer (score 0):

You code have several errors. Looks like you didn't understood how a class and object works.

1. `ImportexportDomains add()` isn't a function. It's called **method**.
2. `$data` variable does not exists on `add` method context. (in fact, it doesn't exist anywhere)
3. You are doing `dd()` on the object, not on the `add` method response.

I know that you want to learn by trying yourself, but there's a nice community called `Laracasts`, that have some very well explained screencasts.

This two series will help you a lot to understand everything!

1. https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners
2. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

You need to pay a month to have access to the videos, but it's only $8!!!

Comment: Sorry , I didnt include all of the code - I've got it working now so will post an answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Method**

```
class ImportexportDomains {
public $error;

public function add($input) {
    $userid = Settings::where('acc_id', Auth::user()->acc_id)->where('setting', 'resellerclub_id')->value('value');
    $apikey = Settings::where('acc_id', Auth::user()->acc_id)->where('setting', 'resellerclub_key')->value('value');
    $cust_email = Client::where('id', $input['client_id'])->value('email');

   $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://httpapi.com/api/customers/details.json?auth-userid=$userid&api-key=$apikey&username=$cust_email");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = json_decode($httpResponse, true);

        if (isset($data['status'])) {
            $error = $data['message'];
        }

 return $this->error = $error;
```

**Controller**

```
    public function store() {
        $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
        $addnew = new ImportexportDomains;
        $addnew->add($input);
        echo $addnew->error;
}
```